# Is money sent by my brother to buy a flat taxable?

Tags: united-states, canada, gift-tax

I am a Canadian citizen living in Halifax.

My brother wants to help me buy a flat and plans to transfer money as a gift ($150,000 USD) from the States to Canada.

Is the transfer taxable?

Answer (score 3):

It is taxable to your brother (assuming he's a US tax resident). Transfer of any amount over $14k per year to any single person (other than spouse) triggers gift tax liability.

Comment: Also, there is an exception to the gift tax that reduces your tax free estate when you die.   For a gift of $150K, I'd look into that to avoid taxes due now.

Comment: right, Alex. A simple form that helps avoid any tax due on gifts up to $5.34M, but goes against that lifetime number.

Comment: @AlexB yes, but essentially it is the same tax. Only the question of *when* you pay it. By the way, the "lifetime exemption" is mandatory, apparently.

Comment: @littleadv If you give a gift now of $150K, giver will owe gift tax.  If you fill out the form making it part of your estate and your estate is < $5M (most people) giver will owe 0 taxes now and 0 taxes at death as part of their estate.

Comment: @AlexB the question was "is it taxable?". The answer was "Yes it is". As to how much money the brother has and how much of the exemption already used - I don't know.